# Flutter web - Razorpay issue

Tags: flutter, dart, razorpay

The Razorpay not working in the flutter web release. I will try to build the web app with these all comments but it's not working

```
 1. flutter build web --release
 2. flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit --release
 3. flutter build web --web-renderer html--release
```

I clicked the Pay button but the Razorpay web HTML page opened and closed but no issues throw, but it's working on local.

Someone give me the solution for this issue. Thank you.

This is the console issue:
[image]

Comment: please mention the issue clearly, you have tried but haven't mentioned the error?

Comment: @gretal There is no issue has returned

Comment: @mahendran check the console inside the network section for error. when you click on the fetch request from razorpay you will get status code

Comment: @Arshal_d Okay, I will check the console.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.